# Java class for handling the response to the alpha vantage API

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, alpha-vantage

I need to make a java class for handling the response to the alpha vantage API, in this case I'm using `TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY`, this API returns intraday time series of the equity specified, covering extended trading hours when applicable, below is an example for JSON output

```json
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-04-16 20:00:00",
        "4. Interval": "5min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (5min)": {
        "2021-04-16 20:00:00": {
            "1. open": "133.4600",
            "2. high": "133.4600",
            "3. low": "133.4600",
            "4. close": "133.4600",
            "5. volume": "313"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tony, please learn how to use Markdown in SO. This will be helpful for you to write better posts in future. I have edited you post for now.

Comment: [markdown editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)